# Looking for a Pauli matrix identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions, spinors

I know some of the better known Pauli Matrix identities. But I don't know (nor could I not figure out or find online) any that could be used for the following expression:

$(\sigma_k)_{\alpha \gamma}(\sigma_j)_{\theta \beta} - (\sigma_j)_{\alpha \gamma}(\sigma_k)_{\theta \beta} = \ ? $

Does anyone know of such an identity?

EDIT:

Here are some identities I have since deduced. I hope they are correct.

\begin{align}
    (\sigma_k)_{\theta}^{\ \gamma}\delta_{\alpha}^{\beta} - (\sigma_k)_{\alpha}^{\ \beta}\delta_{\theta}^{\gamma} &= i \epsilon_{ijk}(\sigma_i)_{\alpha}^{\ \gamma}(\sigma_j)_{\theta}^{\ \beta} \\
    (\sigma_j)_{\alpha}^{\ \beta}(\sigma_k)_{\theta}^{\gamma} - (\sigma_k)_{\alpha}^{\ \beta}(\sigma_j)_{\theta}^{\ \gamma} &= i \epsilon_{jkp}(\delta_{\theta}^{\beta}(\sigma_p)_{\alpha}^{\gamma} - \delta_{\alpha}^{\gamma}(\sigma_p)_{\theta}^{\ \beta}) \\
    \delta_{\alpha}^{\beta} (\sigma_p)_{\theta}^{\ \gamma} + \delta_{\theta}^{\gamma} (\sigma_p)_{\alpha}^{\ \beta} &= \delta_{\theta}^{\beta} (\sigma_p)_{\alpha}^{\ \gamma} + \delta_{\alpha}^{\gamma} (\sigma_p)_{\theta}^{ \ \beta}.
\end{align}

The second one is the kind of one I was looking for.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be an identity for this?

Comment: In worst case, where is the problem in calculating the expression (I don't understand the notation, though), since they are only $2\times 2$ matrices?!

Comment: You know what the [contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/344819/) would be.

Comment: Post edit: Indeed your first identity is equivalent to the second, proven in my answer, given identity (4) of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2).

Comment: I don't see it. Does that contraction not result in $2(\sigma_p)_{\alpha}^{\ \beta}$ on both sides?

Comment: Right you are; good catch; apologies. It is consistent, and follows from completeness. Should have followed my own advice on sparse matrices.

Comment: I haven't managed to find a copy of that Quarks and Leptons book you mentioned below. Is there any other resource you know of that would have a list of these sorts of identities? I have been trying to confirm some SUSY Quantum Mechanics algebras, and this is how I ended up needed these sorts of identities. Even though checking these sorts of things should be straight forward, I am finding it tricky, and I think part of that is not knowing some results I should know.

Comment: [A classic](https://archive.org/details/leptonsquarks0000okun_u6x6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without meaningful differences, flat-raise the antisymmetrized adjoint indices *k* and *j*, to inspect a triplet of ***sparse*** 4×4 Hermitean matrices,
$$
M^{kj}_{\alpha \gamma, \theta\beta}= 
(\sigma^k)_{\alpha \gamma}(\sigma^j)_{\theta \beta} - (\sigma^j)_{\alpha \gamma}(\sigma^k)_{\theta \beta},
$$ one of them real symmetric, and two of them pure imaginary antisymmetric.

In the standard tensor product factor convention, $v_\gamma \otimes w_\beta$,   "*w* into *v*", they
evaluate to
$$
M^{31}= -M^{13}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&0\\ 
1&0&0&-1\\ 
1&0&0&-1\\ 
0&-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix} , \\
M^{12}= -M^{21}=2i\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0\\ 
0&-1&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} , \\
M^{23}= -M^{32}=i\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1&0\\ 
-1&0&0&1\\ 
1&0&0&-1\\ 
0&-1&1&0\end{bmatrix} .
$$
Their eigenvalues are 0,0,2,-2.

By identity, you mean Fierz [transposition  identity](https://doi.org/10.1002/andp.19374220106)? Something like
$$
M^{kj}_{\alpha \gamma, \theta\beta}= i\epsilon ^{kjm} ( \sigma^m_{\alpha\beta} \delta_{\gamma \theta}- \sigma^m_{\theta\gamma} \delta_{\alpha \beta}    ) ~~,
$$ perhaps?
Repeating the above evaluation, now evidently in a different basis, can you see this one has exactly the same eigenvalues as above? Same vanishing partial traces?

Crucially, it checks when multiplied by $\sigma^n_{\gamma\alpha}$ and summing over repeated indices! Of course, setting *γ=θ*  and summing o.r.i. gives you what you'd expect!

---

***Geeky***: All transposition identities rely on Pauli's [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#completeness_anchor),
$$
 2 \delta_{\alpha'\alpha}\delta_{\beta'\beta}= \vec\sigma_{\alpha'\beta'} \cdot \vec\sigma_{\beta\alpha}+ \delta_{\alpha'\beta'}\delta_{\beta\alpha}~~.
$$
For example, the above transposition identity readily results by applying this equality on the left hand side of it, and summing over the repeated indices *α* and *β*, utilizing the equality, and reducing the ensuing matrix products. Twice the above identity ensues by relabelling away the primed indices! This is the proof of the above identity if you haven't worked t out already.

Comment: Thanks for this. I only just now realised that what you called the Fierz transposition identity is probably the my identity 2 above, which I ended up dervining for myself. When you started talking about sparse matrices and wrote out the 4x4 matrices explicitly, I didn't think it was much help to me. Also, the link you give there goes to some research paper written in German. But it was still my dumb mistake for not noticing your post gave what I wanted. Apologies.

Comment: Today, Fierz identities are usually given for  γ matrices. Okun’s Quarks and Leptons  has them in its appendix for σs and λs. The sparse matrices exhibit the change of basis explicitly, which most students have lost in their garlands of indices….

Answer (score 0):

The product of matrix elements is commutative.
$${\sigma_j}_{ab}{\sigma_k}_{cd}-{\sigma_k}_{ab}{\sigma_j}_{cd}=
{\sigma_j}_{ab}{\sigma_k}_{cd}-{\sigma_j}_{cd}{\sigma_k}_{ab}$$
Values depend on choice of basis.